# How do I get corresponding keys to another key from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array in the following format:

```
$array = array (
  0 => 
    array (
      'date' => '2013-03-25',
      'name' => 'Bob',
      'time' => '11'
    ),
  1 => 
    array (
      'date' => '2013-03-25',
      'name' => 'Brian',
      'time' => '13'
    ),
  2 => 
    array (
      'date' => '2013-03-26',
      'name' => 'Jack',
      'time' => '14'
    ),
  3 => 
    array (
      'date' => '2013-03-26',
      'name' => 'Bob',
      'time' => '14'
    )
);
```

I am trying to get the names and corresponding times for each date.  I have got the names using the following method:

```
$array2 = array();
    foreach($array as $item) {
    $array2[$item['date']][] = $item['name'];
    }
```

and then using:

```
foreach($array2[$date] as $name)
```

to run a query on the names returned. But I am not sure how to get the corresponding 'time' key for each 'name' key in the second foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't want to store both `name` and `time` for each `date` key?

```
$array2 = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
  $array2[$item['date']] []= array($item['time'], $item['name']);
}
```

You can reach name and time with this code:

```
foreach ($array2 as $row) {
  $name = $row[0];
  $time = $row[1];
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that's the way to do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$list = array();
foreach ( $array as $k => $item ) {
    $list[$item['date']][] = array(
            $item['name'],
            $item['time']
    );
}

foreach ( $list as $date => $data ) {
    echo $date, PHP_EOL;
    foreach ( $data as $var ) {
        list($name, $time) = $var;
        echo $name, " ", $time, PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
2013-03-25
Bob 11
Brian 13

2013-03-26
Jack 14
Bob 14
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
   $array2[$item['date'][] = array('name' => $item['name'], 'time' => $item['time']);
}

foreach($array2[$date] as $name) {
   echo $name['name'] . ' => ' . $name['time'] . "\n";
}
```